# ValueError using Keras and Tensorflow in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras in R to reproduce a tutorial I found online. Here are my codes:

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(ROCR)

library(devtools)
install_github('rstudio/reticulate',force=T)
library(reticulate)
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(version= "2.3.0")
install_github("rstudio/keras",force=T)
library(keras)
keras::install_keras()
setwd("~/Desktop/TMA_model")

#------------------------------------------------------------#
#-------------- Module 1: Data preparation ------------------#
#------------------------------------------------------------#




source('feature_preprocessing.R')




# if we want to run prediction with pathological data
allFeatures_forModel <- allFeatures_forModel[complete.cases(allFeatures_forModel),]


#------------------------------------------------------------#
#------------ Module 2: Construct Neural Network ------------#
#------------------------------------------------------------#

# split to training and testing set
index <- createDataPartition(allFeatures_forModel$Outcome, p = 0.7, list = F)

X_train <- allFeatures_forModel[index, -ncol(allFeatures_forModel)]
X_test <- allFeatures_forModel[-index, -ncol(allFeatures_forModel)]


# change the outcome to categorical data

train_outcome <- as.vector(as.numeric(as.character(allFeatures_forModel[index, 
ncol(allFeatures_forModel)])))
y_train <- to_categorical(train_outcome)

test_outcome <- as.vector(as.numeric(as.character(allFeatures_forModel[-index, 
ncol(allFeatures_forModel)])))
y_test <- to_categorical(test_outcome)

# model construction !!

model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 
ncol(X_train))%>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>%
layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')


history <- model %>% compile(
 loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
 optimizer = 'adam',
 metrics = c('accuracy')
)

model %>% fit(
  X_train, y_train, 
  epochs = 100, 
  batch_size = 5,
  validation_split = 0.3
)
```

After I run the last chunk of the codes (model fitting part), I got the following error message:

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
 ValueError: in user code:

/Users/mihaoyang/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/Users/mihaoyang/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/Users/mihaoyang/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/Users/mihaoyang/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/Users/mihaoyang/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_r
```

I understand there are some people report similar issues as I had, but seems like none of the resolution will work in my case. I appreciate any suggesiton to tackle this issue, thanks!

Comment: Did you find how to solve it? I am having the same issue and I couldn't fix it